# In PHP why it's only echo the last item And I know In the Array it's More than One

Tags: php, mysql, web

I Have to test `$_POST` before adding it to the database so if any input is empty it will print it but when I submit all items empty it's only print the item in the array? what the problem this My code?

```
$formerror = array ();

if(empty($depdesc))
{
    $formerror [] = " وصف القسم لا يمكن ان يكون فارغ  ";
}
if(empty($depName))
{
    $formerror [] = " اسم القسم لا يمكن ان يكون فارغ  ";
}
#End of check if any empty item 
if(empty($formerror))
{
    echo " No error ";
}else
{
    foreach($formerror as $error);
    {

        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: $formerror it's My array

Comment: This is usually because you overwrite the output in the loop

Comment: excuse me Can you explain More :)

Comment: @adkstar: space isn't a problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of semicolon (`;`) after your `foreach` loop. Can't be there.

Replace

```
foreach($formerror as $error); {...}
                             ^
```

for

```
foreach ($formerror as $error) {
    echo $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop has semicolon (`;`) which is preventing to make it functional in proper way. You just need to remove semicolon right after `foreach()` round braces

`foreach($formerror as $error);`

Should be

`foreach($formerror as $error)`